# Unbold referenced label

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumerate, bold, enumitem

I'm fetching references from an enumeration. The problem is that I want the labels of the enumeration to be bold (hence, I've added a `\textbf` command) but I want the references in the text to be plain text. Can I achieve this in anyway?

Minimal (non)working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\textbf{\Roman{*}})]
\item \label{Your}Your
\item \label{Mama}Mama
\end{enumerate}

'Your' is at \ref{Your} and 'Mama' is at \ref{Mama}. 
(I'd like these references to be in plain text, not bold.)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) provides an equivalent `ref` option to specify a different format for the reference than the `label`. So, you can use `ref=(\Roman*)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\textbf{\Roman{*}}),ref=(\Roman*)]
\item \label{Your}Your
\item \label{Mama}Mama
\end{enumerate}

`Your' is at~\ref{Your} and `Mama' is at~\ref{Mama}. 

\end{document}​
```