# How to refer to single item in custom enumerate

Tags: hyperref, lists, enumitem

I have defined an `enumerate` environment with custom item names: each item should start with a bullet point and then *"Type X case"*, where the X denotes the item number.

Later in the text, I want to refer to an item in the list, but only by its number: for instance, I want to write *"we now refer to case X"* (where X should include a hyperlink to the relevant list item).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=$\bullet\;$\textit{Type \arabic* case}:]
        \item \label{item:type1case} If blah blah
        \item \label{item:type2case} If instead blah
        \item \label{item:type3case} this blah
\end{enumerate}

We now refer to case \ref*{item:type1case}...
\end{document}
```

The final result (in the last phrase) is something like *"We now refer to case • Type 1 case:..."* but I want to have instead *"We now refer to case 1:..."*

How to do this using enumitem package and (possibly) without having to load other packages?

Comment: In essence, you want to have a different `\ref` to what is printed in the `label`. Possible duplicate: [Unbold referenced label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74263/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`enumitem` knows the `ref` option to customise the appearance of labels

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=$\bullet\;$\textit{Type \arabic* case}:,ref=case \arabic*:]
        \item \label{item:type1case} If blah blah
        \item \label{item:type2case} If instead blah
        \item \label{item:type3case} this blah
\end{enumerate}

We now refer to case \ref*{item:type1case}...
\end{document}
```

[image: We now refer to case case 1:...]